# Oracle Flashback Data Archive Version Query With Join?

Tags: database, oracle, join, oracle11g, flashback

I have a situation in where I am trying to essentially get a list of all changes that have occurred on a dataset between two points in time. This seems like a very good case for the VERSIONS BETWEEN keyword in Oracle, but I do not know how to effectively join to other tables and get the results that I want.

Let's say I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
    emp_id        NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    employee_name VARCHAR2(20)
    dept_id       NUMBER(3) NOT NULL
                     CONSTRAINT admin_dept_fkey REFERENCES dept
                     (dept_id))
);

CREATE TABLE dept(
    dept_id    NUMBER(5),
    department VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

If an employee record changes, I need to be able to get the department name as it was at the time the employee record was changed, because it's possible that the employee still belongs to the same department but the department name was changed at some point.

Example:
EMP.VERSIONS_STARTSCN EMP_ID EMPLOYEE_NAME DEPT_ID DEPARTMENT
1                     1      Michael       1       Services
0                     1      Michael       1       Sales

If the database were denormalized and I was storing the department name on the table itself, this would be incredibly easy; however, using the lookup table seems to make it less intuitive.

Things that I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM emp VERSIONS BETWEEN SCN MINVALUE AND MAXVALUE e
JOIN dept d ON d.dept_id = e.dept_id;
```

This will get me the department as it exists today, but that doesn't tell me what it was at the time the employee record was changed.

```
SELECT *
FROM emp VERSIONS BETWEEN SCN MINVALUE AND MAXVALUE e
JOIN dept VERSIONS BETWEEN SCN MINVALUE AND MAXVALUE d
ON d.dept_id = e.dept_id;
```

This isn't good either, because it's going to return multiple rows, one for the employee with each department change where I actually only want the department as it existed at the time the employee record was changed.

I have also tried a couple of inner selects, but it seems like Oracle doesn't allow me to use the VERSIONS_ENDSCN or VERSIONS_STARTTIME in the inner query. Variations I have tried include:

```
SELECT 
    versions_startscn,
    e.employee_name,
    (SELECT department FROM dept AS OF SCN versions_startscn d WHERE d.dept_id = e.dept_id)
FROM emp VERSIONS BETWEEN SCN MINVALUE AND MAXVALUE e

SELECT 
    e.employee_name
    (SELECT department FROM dept AS OF SCN versions_startscn d WHERE d.dept_id = e.dept_id)
FROM(
    SELECT 
        versions_startscn,
        e.employee_name,
    FROM emp VERSIONS BETWEEN SCN MINVALUE AND MAXVALUE e
    )
```

Both of these queries throw an error that VERSIONS_STARTSCN is not declared.

I feel like this has to be a fairly common use case, but I haven't been able to find any examples of using VERSIONS BETWEEN with joins. I have come up with a way to do this which involves opening a cursor with the employee changes BETWEEN SCN MINVALUE AND MAXVALUE, selecting the SCN into a variable, and selecting the changes from the emp table and DEPT AS OF SCN into a nested table type, but this seems like a lot of work to do something that seems fairly straightforward. If anyone has any ideas, it would be much appreciated.

I am currently using v11.2.0.4.

Comment: hi did you managed this out ?

Answer (score 0):

I have almost similar requirement

I could only think of doing this by checking if the version times of one table lies between version times of other table.  Either start or Endtime should be present in between start and endtime of other table and vice versaa. But this is very costly and slow.

```
nvl(tblB.versions_Endtime,tblB.versions_starttime) >=  tblA.versions_starttime and  nvl(tblB.versions_Endtime,tblB.versions_starttime) <=  nvl(tblA.versions_endtime, to_timestamp('9999-01-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'))
```

OR

```
nvl(tblA.versions_Endtime,tblA.versions_starttime) >=  tblB.versions_starttime and 
nvl(tblA.versions_Endtime,tblA.versions_starttime) <=  nvl(tblB.versions_endtime, to_timestamp('9999-01-01 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'))
```

Comment: I've added code formatting for clarity but it is unclear whether the "OR" refers to two alternative statements, or is a logical OR which should be included to make just one statement..